# Найти минимальное количество движений, необходимое для перераспределения фишек

Tags: c#, алгоритм

> Хосе поставил круглый покерный стол для своих друзей, чтобы у каждого из мест за столом было одинаковое количество покерных фишек. Но когда он отвернулся, кто-то перегруппировал все фишки, чтобы их больше не было равное количество у каждого места. Теперь Хосе необходимо перераспределить фишки, чтобы количество фишек у каждого места было одинаковым для всех, прежде чем приедут друзья. Но Хосе очень дотошный: чтобы он не потерял фишки в этом процессе, он только перемещает фишки между соседними местами. Более того, он только двигает фишки по одной. Каково минимальное количество движений фишек, которые Хосе нужно будет сделать, чтобы вернуть фишки обратно в равное для всех количество.

Подскажите с какой стороны подойти?
Например

```
Test 1
Input:
фишки: [1, 5, 9, 10, 5]
Expected Output:
12
Test 2
Input:
фишки: [1, 2, 3]
Expected Output:
1
```

Comment: Каков размер массива?

Comment: Сначала конвертировать массив количеств в массив отклонений (так проще работать). Затем выполнять перемещение из наибольшего положительного элемента в ближайший отрицательный (обнуляя один из них), пока все элементы не обнулятся. Доказать, что при этом получится минимальное количество перемещений, не могу, да и лень...

Comment: @MBo Судя по задаче длинна массива не объявлена,то есть любой

Comment: @Akina, что  есть массив отклонений?

Comment: Количество лишних (+) или нехватающих (-) фишек относительно конечного (среднего арифметического) количества на данном месте.

Comment: @Akina. Нет. Например, (..., 5, 5, 6, 5, 4, 10, 5, 0, 5, 5, ...). Баланс - 5 фишек. Оптимальная стратегия - сбросить все лишние фишки из пика 10 в яму 0 справа. А яму 4 заполнить из пика 6. А ваш алгоритм начнет с того, что сбросит одну фишку из 10 налево в ближайшую яму 4 и из-за этого уже очевидным образом потеряет оптимальность. Оптимально - 12 шагов, ваш вариант делает 14.

Comment: @AnT Возможно, я как бы не настаиваю на оптимальности.

Comment: @Akina: На оптимальности настаивает условие задачи.

Comment: @AnT Ну как бы не хочется превращать задачу в переборную... а с чего-то начинать всё равно нужно.

Comment: @Akina Идея хорошая, но мы должны ,скидывать фишки в соседние ямы или справа или слева.

Comment: @AnT вопрос только в том, что нужно фишки скидывать только в соседние ямы. Как вы нашли баланс в 5 фишек? Какая логика?

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch В смысле - "как нашли"? У вас в задаче количество мест заранее известно и общее количество фишек заранее известно. Делим второе на первое (обязано делиться нацело) и сразу получаем "баланс" - целевое количество фишек на каждом месте. А в моем примере я не "нашел" баланс, я его взял с потолка, чисто для примера. Про "соседние" ямы - верно.

Comment: @AnT Получается, да, что действительно, по входящему массиву,мы видим количество игроков и количество фишек.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эту задачу можно свести к графовой проблеме "[Поток минимальной стоимости](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/min_cost_flow)".

Вершины с избытком поставим в левую долю, вершины с недостатком - в правую. 
Между вершинами левой и правой доли проложим рёбра, пропускная способность которых соответствует возможному количеству перекладываемых фишек для данной пары вершин (минимум из абс. значений левого избытка и правого недостатка), а стоимость единицы потока - круговому расстоянию между вершинами.

Кроме этого, вводим две фиктивные вершины - исток и сток, соединённые с левой долей и правой соответственно ребрами с пропускной способностью, равной избытку или недостатку соотв. вершины (в `networkx` реализации этого не потребовалось)

Потом ищем поток минимальной стоимости размером в общий избыток.

Для примера @Ant с использованием питоновской библиотеки `networkx` получается перекладывание одной фишки из 6 в 4 и пяти из 10 в 0.

Стоимость `1*ac.weight + 5*bd.weight = 12`

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node('a', demand = -1)
G.add_node('b', demand = -5)
G.add_node('c', demand = 1)
G.add_node('d', demand = 5)
G.add_edge('a', 'c', weight = 2, capacity = 1)
G.add_edge('a', 'd', weight = 5, capacity = 1)
G.add_edge('b', 'c', weight = 1, capacity = 1)
G.add_edge('b', 'd', weight = 2, capacity = 5)
flowDict = nx.min_cost_flow(G)
print(flowDict)

>{'a': {'c': 1, 'd': 0}, 'b': {'c': 0, 'd': 5}, 'c': {}, 'd': {}}
```

Comment: А как тут увидеть сколько шагов надо сделать по перемещению фишек? И можно ли как то это все связять с с#?

Comment: Если не касаться графа, то  алгоритм такой.Если стопки не равны, то цикл. Определяются стопки с наименьшим количеством фишек.
Из найденных стопок выбирается та рядом с которой самая большая стопка. Из большей стопки перекладывается в меньшую.
Возврат на 1-й шаг

Comment: 'a': {'c': 1, означает, что 1 фишка перекладывается из узла a в c. Расстояние 2, так что это два шага перекладывания. На c# можно найти реализацию min cost flow или самому написать

Comment: "то алгоритм такой" - это жадный алгоритм, 
 один и вариантов которого предложен Akina. Но уже выяснилось, что он не всегда даёт оптимальный результат

Comment: А всего сколько шагов, это в ручном режиме считать?

Comment: weight(a,c)*1+weight(b,d)*5=12

Comment: Поток минимальной стоимости это куб минимум. Лобовое решение квадрат. Мне кажется можно ещё быстрее.

Comment: @pavel Возможно, есть. По размеру данных автор ничего не ответил, так что я как сразу про венгерку подумал, так в другие стороны и не копал. Лобовое решение, которое я рассматривал, кроме квадрата ещё могло вовлечь количество избытка

Comment: @MBo ответ за квадрат сейчас напишу. но мне кажется тут n log n или вообще линия.

Comment: @MBo прочитайте мой ответ. Можете подправить. Писал сумбурно чуть, что не понятно спрашивайте чтобы расписал.

Answer (score 2):

Решение не использует сторонних библиотек, сложных алгоритмов и пишется руками. Код не привожу, но проблем там не будет.

Давайте решим это задачу если бы был обычный стол (не круглый). Алгоритм простой. Идём сначала. Имеем монеты "в руке". Если сейчас у игрока больше чем надо монет, мы забираем лишние в руку. Если не хватает - отдаём с руки (да в руке может быть отрицательное число). После каждого шага добавляем к ответу модуль того что в руке.

Пример для `5, 5, 6, 5, 4, 10, 5, 0, 5, 5` будет (пара сумма + рука)

```
 0 0
 0 0
 1 1
 2 1
 2 0
 7 5
12 5
12 0
12 0
```

Ответ 12.

Теперь если у нас  слот круглый. По сути, не нарушая общности его можно разрезать в *любом* месте, главное знать сколько фишек уйдёт через границу не в том направлении обхода.

В крайнем случае эту величину можно перебрать. Но зачем?

Дальше читать только если нужна оптимизация.

Что будет, если у нас  этих расчётах изменится начальное значение. Тогда если рука имела тот же знак что и начальное значение, то сумма растёт, иначе - уменьшается. Причём всё очень хорошо считается. Главное - не пропустить момент смены знака на 0. Таким образом мы уже можем перебирать не все начальные значения руки а только те, которые совпадают с одним из текущих показателей. Это уже чистый O(n^2).

Дальше больше. Переформулируем. У нас есть некий набор значений. Мы можем сдвигать его на одно и тоже значение, так что сумма модулей была минимальная. Это уже известная задача. Это простая задача. Нужно что бы было поровну элементов больше и меньше 0. Для этого можно выбрать медиану (не среднее!).

Итого уже O(n) - порядковая статистика штука известная.

Будут вопросы - пишите. Решение не очевидное.

Comment: Кажется очевидным, что такой простой "метод бульдозера" работает. Правда, мне и с жадным так казалось ;) Как-то трудно в этой задаче критерий корректности увидеть.

Comment: @MBo если про часть где я говорю что медиану надо использовать то легко. Пусть у нас оптимальный баланс не поровну. Сдвинем границу на 1 в строну там где меньше элементов. Мы получили результат не лучше. Отсюда число 0 (которые стали +/-1) было не меньше чем разница между балансами. Отсюда мы вязли медиану. Мне показалось это очевидно :D

Answer (score 1):

Задача представляет собой классический пример сбалансированной [Транспортной задачи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0), в которой кучки с избытком фишек выступают в роли пунктов производства, кучки с недостатком фишек выступают в роли пунктов потребления, а стоимость перевозки равна кратчайшему расстоянию (в кольце) между этими кучками. Решать ее можно любыми методами решения транспортной задачи, в том числе путем сведения к задаче максимального потока минимальной стоимости (mincost maxflow).

Однако упрощенная структура задачи (расстояния в кольце) скорее всего допускает менее общее, более остроумное и эффективное решение.